# Springboot The alias 'Int' is already mapped to the value 'java.lang.Integer'

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

When I rename the application packagename and try to start springboot, I get an error message. The error message is as follows:

17:36:19.198 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - [log,87] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' defined in class path resource [net/changhai/framework/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilterFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [net/changhai/framework/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'shiroFilterFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [net/changhai/framework/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRealm': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'menuService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sysMenuServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'menuMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sysMenuMapper' defined in file [D:\dev\cube2\ch-system\target\classes\net\changhai\system\mapper\SysMenuMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: The alias 'Int' is already mapped to the value 'java.lang.Integer'.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I met the same issue, I didn't map any alias in my batis, but it gives the error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are binding alias 'Int' to some class.
By default it is binding to java.lang.Integer, so it is preserved by MyBatis and you should not rebind it to another one.